# CSS class depending on list items text length

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way to set different classes to items in a list depending on the length of the value? Preferrably plain JS or jQuery.

I have a list with fixed width, and the text amount in each list item varies. The list items has backgrounds which can't be repeated or extend, and because of that I would need to make different backgrounds (classes) for different text lengths.

1-15 chars would be taken care of by the default css class, 15-30 chars would need an extra class with the extended background and 30-45 chars would need another class etc.

Being a total n00b in JS I just can't manage to figure this out, even though I've been fiddling with it for the last two days...

Thanks a lot in advance,

Eirik.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#myList li').each(function() {
    var length = ($(this).html().length);

    if (length > 30) {
        $(this).addClass('longest');
    }
    else if (length > 15) {
        $(this).addClass('long');
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass('default');
    }  
});
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WPS3M/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.listItem').each(function(){
  var content = $(this).html();
  if(var.length > 30){
     $(this).addClass('Over30');
  }
   .....etc
```

Set this to run after the content has loaded e.g.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $('.listItem').each(function(){
     var content = $(this).html();
     if(var.length > 30){
        $(this).addClass('Over30');
     }
   .....etc
 }
```